# jQuery initialize dynamically loaded content

Tags: jquery

I have various sections within a page of content that dynamically get replaced based on what the user selects via a click event. I'm using a tooltip plugin on the clickable items as well. Depending what is clicked will then dynamically replace other clickable items.

I've solved the initializing of click event through .delegate() but am not sure how to initialize the .tooltip() plugin for the dynamic content.

Code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // This works...
    $("#content").delegate(".etype", "click", function () {
        var elem = $(this);
        var parent_id = $(this).attr('rel').replace("id_", "");
        $.ajax({
            url: '/panel/' + parent_id,
            success: function(data) {
                var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                for (var key in obj) {
                    $('#'+obj[key]['panel']+'panelwrapper .panelcontainer').html(obj[key]['content']);
                    $('.'+obj[key]['etype']+'_type.etype').removeClass('selected');
                    elem.addClass('selected');
                }
            }
        });     
    });

    // This doesn't work for new AJAX content.
    // Not sure if .delegate() can be used here...
    $(".etype.showtip").tooltip({
        effect: 'fade', 
        position: 'center right',
        opacity: 0.7,
        offset: [3, 0],
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution here...

[tooltip for Ajax-loaded triggers - jQuery live?](http://flowplayer.org/tools/forum/30/37281)

```
$(document).delegate("[title]", "mouseenter", function() {
    if (!$(this).data("tooltip")) {
        $(this).tooltip({position: "top center", offset: [-7, 10]});
        $(this).trigger("mouseenter");
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check with [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) event

```
$(".etype.showtip").live("tooltip", function(){
    effect: 'fade', 
    position: 'center right',
    opacity: 0.7,
    offset: [3, 0],
});
```

Edit.

Ohh i am sorry for recomending live mothod.

As far as I see the problem is that the tooltip function is called just once **(on window.load)**.

Try to call that method on load event as well as ajax success function.

Comment: .live() has been replaced with .delegate() for jQuery 1.4 - 1.6 and .on() for 1.7. Also I'm not sure how to pass parameters within the function. The above approach doesn't work with .delegate() because inside the function it is expecting cammands rather than parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the extra detail. That is sort of what I ended up doing (function to initialise .tooltip called from document.ready and .ajax success function but it just doesn't feel very 'clean'. Was really hoping to be able to get something like .delegate() to this if possible.